# Bison parser won't look-ahead for token

Tags: parsing, bison, regex-lookarounds

I have the following parser grammar (this is a small sample):

```
expr:
        ident assignop expr
        {
            $$ = new NAssignment(new NAssignmentIdentifier(*$1), $2, *$3);
        } |
        STAR expr %prec IDEREF
        {
            $$ = new NDereferenceOperator(*$2);
        } |
        STAR expr assignop expr %prec IDEREF
        {
            $$ = new NAssignment(new NAssignmentDereference(*$2), $3, *$4);
        } |
        ... ;

...

assignop:
        ASSIGN_EQUAL |
        ASSIGN_ADD |
        ASSIGN_SUBTRACT |
        ASSIGN_MULTIPLY |
        ASSIGN_DIVIDE ;
```

Now I'm trying to parse any of the following lines:

```
*0x8000 = 0x7000;
*mem = 0x7000;
```

However, Bison keeps seeing "*mem" and reducing on the 'STAR expr' rule and not performing look-ahead to see whether 'STAR expr assignop...' matches.  As far as I understand Bison, it should be doing this look-ahead.  My closest guess is that %prec is turning off look-ahead or something strange like that, but I can't see why it would do so (since the prec values are equivalent).

How do I make it perform look-ahead in this case?

**EDIT:**

The state that it enters when encountering 'STAR expr' is:

```
state 45

   28 expr: STAR expr .
   29     | STAR expr . assignop expr
   35     | expr . binaryop expr

    $default  reduce using rule 28 (expr)

    assignop  go to state 81
    binaryop  go to state 79
```

So I don't understand why it's picking $default when it could pick assignop (note that the order of the rules in the parser.y file don't affect which one it picks in this case; I've tried reordering the assignop one above the standard 'STAR expr').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by creating another rule 'deref' like so:

```
deref:
        STAR ident
        {
            $$ = new NDereferenceOperator(*$<ident>2);
        } |
        STAR numeric
        {
            $$ = new NDereferenceOperator(*$2);
        } |
        STAR CURVED_OPEN expr CURVED_CLOSE
        {
            $$ = new NDereferenceOperator(*$3);
        } |
        deref assignop expr
        {
            if ($1->cType == "expression-dereference") // We can't accept NAssignments as the deref in this case.
                $$ = new NAssignment(new NAssignmentDereference(((NDereferenceOperator*)$1)->expr), $2, *$3);
            else
                throw new CompilerException("Unable to apply dereferencing assignment operation to non-dereference operator based LHS.");
        } ;
```

replacing both rules in 'expr' with a single 'deref'.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if `IDREF` is higher precedence than `ASSIGN_EQUAL`, `ASSIGN_ADD`, etc.  Specifically, in this case with the raw parser (before precedence is applies), you have shift/reduce conflicts between the `expr: STAR expr` rule and the various `ASSIGN_`XXX tokens.  The precedence rules you have resolve all the conflicts in favor of the reduce.

The `assignop` in the state is a goto, not a shift or reduce, so doesn't enter into the lookahead or token handling at all -- gotos only occur after some token has been shifted and then later reduced to the non-terminal in question.

Comment: Oops! I thought I deleted this question since I solved it already.  I better add my answer now...